# Power series expansion requirements

Tags: limits, functions, inequality, power-series, taylor-expansion

Hello stackexchange folks :)

I have a question regarding the assumptions made right before you choose to expand or approximate a function by a power series.

Specifically I have the function:

\begin{equation*}
\psi_p = n_iln(\frac{n_i}{Np_i}).
\end{equation*}

Now in the next step it is assumed that $|n_i - Np_i| < Np_i$ and therefore we can expand to second order in $|n_i - Np_i|$ obtaining:

\begin{equation*}
\psi_p \approx \frac{1}{2} \frac{(n_i-Np_i)^2}{Np_i}.
\end{equation*}

(If it is any help then $N = n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_m$)

My question is: Why do we require that $|n_i - Np_i| < Np_i$? And why do we expand in $|n_i - Np_i|$? Are there any way to visualize or derive that this must be true if we want to make a lower order expansion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the first formula is correct ? I wonder if there is a typo.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, there was a typo, but no more. (I had a fraction in the denominator of ln which was a mistake)

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting 
$$\psi_p = n_i\log\Big(\frac{n_i}{Np_i}\Big)=n_i\log\Big(\frac{Np_i+n_i-Np_i}{Np_i}\Big)=n_i\log\Big(1+\frac{n_i-Np_i}{Np_i}\Big)$$ and you want to use the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$; this is only valid if $|x|<1$.

However, I do not see how you arrive to your last expression.

Comment: Good answer, thanks a lot. I'm not sure how he ended up with that approximation either. When I expand in $n_i - Np_i$ around $n_i = 0$ I get the second order term that he wrote plus a first order term.

Comment: The expansion is around $\frac{n_i-Np_i}{Np_i}=0$